# php limit foreach to only show item once

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried for a couple of days to figure out how to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am using woocommerce to show one variation of each colour.

But I cannot find out how to limit them.

As for right now I have made a script which removes the duplicates but I don't think it's that good of a solution.

The code has been taken from inside the loop on an archive page.

The code I am working with is as following:

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms("pa_color");
foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
    <?php $variations = $product->get_available_variations(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($variations as $attributes => $value): ?>
        <?php $color = $value[attributes][attribute_pa_color]; ?>
        <?php if ($color === $term->slug): ?>
            <?php echo $color; ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So as you can see i first get the colours for the product with get_terms and then use a foreach loop, I don't know if it is the right way to do it, so i hope you guys can help.

Comment: Why do you have so many php tags all over the script, you only need one start tag the start, and an end tag at the end.

Comment: I know but when i develop i can better focus like this, and when i'm finished i correct in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [break](http://fr.php.net/break) statement

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $row){
    if(++$i > 2) break;
}
```

example the first two items. Change '2' to whatever number you want.